# aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution: error creating CloudFront Distribution: AccessDenied:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting below error message when I try to create aws cloudfront using terraform. This is for just practice purpose..

AWS error message

```sh
aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution: error creating CloudFront   Distribution: AccessDenied: You don't have permission to access the S3 bucket for CloudFront logs: mylogs.s3.amazonaws.com If you're using IAM, you need s3:GetBucketAcl and s3:PutBucketAcl permissions to create a distribution or to update log settings for an existing distribution. In addition, the S3 ACL for the bucket must grant you FULL_CONTROL.
        status code: 403, request id: ca2cb482-77ee-11e9-b657-333a65da9ea7
```

Below is the code.

https://github.com/vaibhavjpr/terraformpractice/blob/master/cloudfront.tf

Any hint to fix this will be really helpful for me.

Comment: Im getting the same error. What did you do to fix this ?

Comment: did you manage to fix it?

Comment: try a random name to make sure u are not using an already used bucket, also make sure you can access the bucket, in order to check that you can create one with PUBLIC access (just to make sure you can create it, reminder: never create a public s3 bucket)

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess `mylogs.s3.amazonaws.com` is not yours S3 bucket, someone probably created it long time ago. S3 bucket names are unique across AWS, I recommend following [official AWS S3 bucket naming practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules).

Comment: I am creating the above bucket "mylogs.s3.amazonaws.com" here.                                S3 template is present in this link ```https://github.com/vaibhavjpr/terraformpractice/blob/master/s3.tf```   Do you think that I need to give permission on S3 log delivery group?

Answer (score 0):

Other than using a unique bucket name that you have access to, also make sure to use the S3 bucket domain name instead of the actual S3 bucket name

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I copied an example from terraform, and it has the  following configuration as an example:

```
logging_config {
    include_cookies = false
    bucket          = "mylogs.s3.amazonaws.com"
    prefix          = "myprefix"   
}
```

If you are not using logging, you can simply delete that part of the code, or you can create and configure another bucket to store your logs.